# Flush Keyboard Buffer x86 assembly using int 16h

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, bootloader

I have a doubt because my code is not working. I'm implementing a bootloader that runs the code below, when I try to load it only works in a few cases, like I explain below. My code is the next one:

```
ChangeGameState:
    mov cx, 00H      ;Here I make a delay
    mov dx, 3240H    ;.
    mov ah, 86H      ;.
    int 15h          ;.

    jmp DetectKeyPress

DetectKeyPress:
    mov ah, 01h 
    int 16h 
    jz noKeyInBuffer 
    xor ah, ah 
    int 16h 
    jmp exitKeyPress 

    noKeyInBuffer:
        xor ax, ax 

    exitKeyPress:   
        jmp ProcessKey

ProcessKey:
    cmp ah, 0
    je ExitKey
    cmp ah, 'd'
    je ChangeDir1
    cmp ah, 's'
    je ChangeDir2
    cmp ah, 'a'
    je ChangeDir3
    cmp ah, 'w'
    je ChangeDir4

ExitKey:
    jmp ChangeGameState

ChangeDir1:
    ;DO SOMETHING1
    jmp ChangeGameState

ChangeDir2:
    ;DO SOMETHING2
    jmp ChangeGameState

ChangeDir3:
    ;DO SOMETHING3
    jmp ChangeGameState

ChangeDir4:
    ;DO SOMETHING4
    jmp ChangeGameState
```

Now, when I try to press keys S, A and W it doesn't works, only if I press D key.. Any idea of what's going on??

Comment: What do you see when you single-step it in BOCHS, or any other x86 simulator that has a built-in debugger?

Comment: Just the program stops.. Nothing happens

Comment: So what values are in what register?  That's what the **debugger** that's built into BOCHS is for.

Comment: I installed Bochs and the code doesn't works since line #1..

Comment: I can't even tell what you're trying to say.  Does this help? http://bochs.sourceforge.net/doc/docbook/user/internal-debugger.html

Comment: No, but thank you so much @PeterCordes

Comment: Do you need to init your segment registers?  I don't see you using any static memory, so the code you've shown is position-independent and shouldn't care what `ds` is set to.  But maybe the "DO SOMETHING" blocks are having a problem?  Also note that `jmp DetectKeyPress` is redundant, because it's jumping to the next instruction anyway.

Comment: I'm using "org 100h".. I saw that I don't need "jmp DetectKeyPress".. "DO SOMETHING2.3.4" it's ok, because is almost the same code than "DO SOMETHING1".. My code only jump to "ChangeDir1" if I press D key, if I press S, A or W it does't works...

Comment: So use a debugger to find out what's actually happening when it doesn't work.  That's *by far* the best approach.  Developing in asm without a debugger is like trying to build something blindfolded.  It's worth taking the time now to learn how to use a debugger, because it will save you hours on many future problems you run into.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much @PeterCordes, I'll look for a debugger

Comment: BOCHS is the one that's normally recommended for this.  See also other links in the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info), but there aren't many bootloader links.  IDK if dosbox has a debugger or anything like that.

Comment: This code looks familiar lol

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `int 16h` returns the *scancode* in `ah`, and the ASCII character in `al`. So while your code is testing the scancode of the key, you should be testing the ASCII character.

So, in `ProcessKey`, change `cmp ah, ...` to `cmp al, ...`.

Comment: you changed all 5 statements?

Comment: @ArturoSalas Then something **else** in you code must be wrong. Since you provided no [mcve], you should feel lucky just to have got this answer, which solves you a bug and that you should consider accepting.